# Extracting text from an interview transcript with Python regex

Tags: python, regex, text-extraction

I'm using Python 3 to analyse transcripts of political interviews. But I'm struggling to get regex working properly.

I have lots of .txt files in this format:

```
NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

PRIME MINISTER:

Aenean tempus feugiat leo, ut tristique mauris tempus sed.

NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Aenean id felis neque. Nam ornare turpis et dolor elementum auctor.

PRIME MINISTER:

Donec rutrum, erat a faucibus consectetur, mi nisi rhoncus augue, et rutrum purus lorem id arcu.

NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Aenean id felis neque. Nam ornare turpis et dolor elementum auctor.
```

`NAME_OF_JOURNALIST` is a variable that changes in every file. I'm not interested in what the journalist says, only what the prime minister says. So I need to isolate and extract the sections of text that begin with `PRIME MINISTER` and end with `NAME_OF_JOURNALIST`.

I've tried using the following regex:

`PRIME MINISTER.+(?!PRIME)(?!MINISTER)\b[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]+\b`

But it doesn't capture the text I need. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'(?sm)PRIME MINISTER:\s*(.*?)(?=^[A-Z][\w ]*:|\Z)', s)`](https://regex101.com/r/8RGPFn/1), or if the PRIME MINISTER should be part of the match, `re.findall(r'(?sm)PRIME MINISTER:\s*.*?(?=^[A-Z][\w ]*:|\Z)', s)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
PRIME MINISTER:[\n]+(.+)
```

https://regex101.com/r/LhsujV/1

Your regex doesn't seem to match anything. Not sure what your are trying to achieve.

Comment: Only works if the text of the PM is always on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` with Lookbehind & Lookahead

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

PRIME MINISTER:

Aenean tempus feugiat leo, ut tristique mauris tempus sed.

NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Aenean id felis neque. Nam ornare turpis et dolor elementum auctor.

PRIME MINISTER:

Donec rutrum, erat a faucibus consectetur, mi nisi rhoncus augue, et rutrum purus lorem id arcu.

NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:

Aenean id felis neque. Nam ornare turpis et dolor elementum auctor."""

for text in re.findall(r"(?<=PRIME MINISTER:).*?(?=NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:)", s, flags=re.DOTALL):
    print(text.strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Aenean tempus feugiat leo, ut tristique mauris tempus sed.
Donec rutrum, erat a faucibus consectetur, mi nisi rhoncus augue, et rutrum purus lorem id arcu.
```

Comment: Does not work properly if the PM has the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

We can use lookarounds here like this:

```
(?<=PRIME MINISTER:\s)[\s\S]*?(?=NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:\s|\s*\Z)
```

[**Demo**](http://(?%3C=PRIME%20MINISTER:%5Cs)[%5Cs%5CS]*?(?=NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:%5Cs))

**Explantion**

- `(?<=PRIME MINISTER:\s)` a postive lookbehind to anchor the beginning
- `[\s\S]*?` a modified . matching across lines, lazy
- `(?=NAME_OF_JOURNALIST:\s|\s*\Z)` a positive lookahead that matches a subsequent journalist name or the end of the string `\Z`.

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/ZCwJO1)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

reg=re.compile(r"(?ms)^\s*PRIME MINISTER:\s*[\r\n]+(.+?)^[\s\w]+:\s*$")
for m in reg.finditer(text):
    print(m.group(1))

"""
(?ms)                           m: multiline, s: dot matches at all, \n, too;

^\s*PRIME MINISTER:\s*[\r\n]+   section begins with a line starting(^) with some/none spaces and PM, and ending with newline;

^[\s\w]+:\s*$                   section stops at a line starting with words and ending($) with ":" and some/none spaces.

(.+?)                           the wanted content
"""
```

The journalist name is variable. The PM's content can contain ":", too.